Is there any way to check the originality of Windows OS?
I just got an SSD installed. The tech that do my laptop also install a new Windows OS on the SSD.
But, I'm wondering the originality of the Windows OS that the "tech" installed, is there any way to check it? It is still 'not activated'.
Why I was wondering that in the first place? I live in a country where it is very common to use a cracked copy of Windows OS (even though now, Windows is free to install, you just need to pay to activate it).
When I got the SSD installed, I assume that the "tech" would only install SSD. But, when I got my laptop back, apparently the "tech" also install a Windows OS in it.
I also found a KMS Auto Lite with a .kuyhAa extension. When I tried to look it online, it shows me some sketchy website. I'm assuming the tech use it either to get Windows OS or MS Office. And, I don't want to deal with any risk of pirated stuff in the future.
But, I'm wondering is there a valid way to "confirm" whether the Windows OS is genuine or crack?

Genuine or not is not a property of the Windows setup medium but rather of the license and activation, nowadays.

If its said that its not activated, then you should just try to activate it. If it works, assume they did it properly. If it doesn't, ask them. It is possible they used an OEM license, and it is also possible a license is already present in the hardware. Then its just a matter of activating it. And if activation doesn't work, contact the shop.

@LPChip My laptop is actually a second-hand (bought a long time ago). When my parents bought it, the Windows is already activated using retail license. But, I have no information abt the license (ppl said that it should come with a sticker, but when my parents bought it, they were only given the laptop and the bag). And at that time, it only use HDD, so the OS is in the HDD. Is it possible to move the license to the OS that is install on the SSD?

@LPChip I add another detail in the question.

There are two completely different issues that should be addressed separately: (1) Whether the tech used an installation medium from a dubious source (potentially infected with malware) for installing Windows (as was common many years ago). This is unlikey, since you can just download the ISOs directly from MS nowadays. Still, a clean reinstall can alleviate any doubts. (2) Whether you have a valid license to use Windows. That's a legal question that depends on a lot of factors, including whether your notebook was initially bought with Windows and on your local jurisdiction.

From Microsoft blog Go to Settings > Update & Security > Activation. "If it says "Windows is activated with a digital license," your copy is genuine."

However, you can always go directly to Microsoft, download the Windows ISO, and install it to repair Windows, keeping files. One reason to do so is to fix any issues with the operating system.

PCs sold by major OEMs from the last decade or so have had the Windows key embedded in the BIOS where it's read automatically by the installer instead of on a sticker (typically on the bottom of the laptop); so it's unlikely that the person who worked on your machine would have needed to use any sort of crack to install Windows.
If you have any concern about if they might have acted unethically though, you can download installers for Windows directly from Microsoft and do a clean install of your own.

Hey, I actually consider to do a clean install on the SSD. But, before doing the installation, should I format the SSD first (since it's already have Windows installed in it)? or it'll be formated automatically?

@aki: When I do a clean install, I create a USB boot stick with Rufus and then boot from the stick. During the installation process the installer will ask you on which partition you want to install Windows. At this point, you have the option to delete all existing partitions. If you then select the remaining "unallocated space" as the installation target, Windows will create its default partitioning scheme.
